# How to save a file in vscode-remote SSH with a non-root user privileges

Tags: vscode-remote

I am not able to save any files on my remote server with VSCode Remote SSH because I am not a root user.

I've followed the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) about how to set up ssh with SSH config file but even if my user as sudo privileges, I can't find any options in VSCode to save with sudo.

here is my SSH config file `/Users/geoff/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gcpmain
    User geoff
    HostName <IP_ADDRESS>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gc_rsa
```

Obviously, when I try to save any files that require sudo I have this expected error message:

```
Failed to save 'default': Unable to write file (NoPermissions
 (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 
'/etc/nginx/sites-available/default')
```

Is there any way that I can force VSCode to save as sudo?
Thanks a lot for your answers! :)

Comment: I had this issue and just doing a `$ sudo chown -R non_root_username /path/to/directory` did the trick

Comment: For anyone just learning, it should be noted that @Rahul's comment alters the file ownership for all files within the directory which may have other repercussions, such as breaking some services that expect to be the owner of certain files.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I recommend this VSCode extension: [Save as Root in Remote SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yy0931.save-as-root)

Install the extension on a window opened with Remote-SSH and use "Save as Root" in the command palette instead of Ctrl+S.

Basically, it reads the contents of the editor and [calls the sudo command](https://github.com/yy0931/save-as-root/blob/7ac46b1d636ee9131d3d88ab12e9d67ecdaad1dd/extension.js#L11) to overwrite the file.

Comment: One issue with this method is that you can't *explore* as `root`. You can only save (and open) publicly readable files.

Comment: It works! Thanks buddy. Was such a pain to deal with file permissions.

Comment: Also, after installing this great extension, you can configure `Keybindings` with the `when` clause `remote.sshContext` to save the file as root in the remote ssh session, and with the `when` clause `!remote.sshContext` to save the file as usual in the local one. So, after that you can use `Ctrl + C` to save the file in both situations.

Comment: Did you mean editing the Keybinding of `Ctrl + S` @almaceleste

Comment: @SouravOrii, yes, of course. I mean the `Ctrl + S` keybinding. my typo. thanx for correcting me.

Answer (score 73):

```
sudo chown -R $USER /path/to/folder
```

This worked fine for me!

Comment: It works for me. Note that: run this command in your container. For example, you run with the user of docker, then change the `myuser` to docker.  In my case, I ran `NV_GPU=0 nvidia-docker run -d --user docker  -v /home/goodman/myproject:/home/docker/app -t goodman:torch_demo`. Inside the container, run `sudo chown -R docker /home/docker/app`.

Comment: @umitu's recommended VS Code extension is better for most scenarios.  Repeatedly changing file permissions to test something that is overwritten by an automated process isn't efficient.

Comment: This is a pretty poor answer. 1. because I'm sure the OP knows how to change file permissions, and understands the error enough to know that doing so would make the error go away. So doesn't really answer the question of how to do this in vscode. And 2. because this is not efficient. And 3. files owned by root are typically owned by root for good reason. Imagine if you had a malicious process on your server that was trying to access root owned files every 1 minute. Changing them for a few minutes when not necessary could be disastrous.

Comment: This is a really bad idea and will likely break your linux system if you apply this to key configuration files and folders, because they will no longer be owned by the correct user - which in some cases will be `root`, but in other cases might be some application specific linux user

Answer (score 23):

I also met the same issue when using vs code to ssh login CentOS with non-root account.

The **true reason** is: Your user account ("geoff" here) need to get the permission of the destination directory first.

```sh
sudo setfacl -R -m u:geoff:rwx /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

for you case.

More general usage:

```sh
sudo setfacl -R -m u:username:rwx /path/to/directory
```

This command will help you get the permission of the directory `/path/to/directory`, without influencing the permissions of any other user or group. Not recommend to use `chown`. This solution can be used on Mac/Linux.

When you finish running above command, you can edit and save in VS code. May it be helpful for you.

Comment: @Geoff Hey, FYI. I tried, solved the similar issue.

Comment: Great answer, much better than nuking the ownership to yourself :)

Comment: just wanted to support this answer and also add that I did a bit of an alternative by adding the user to the group for the folder by doing `usermod -aG <target_group> <initial_user>`. Make sure that the group permissions can write :)

Comment: Unless you want to use the Save as Root in SSH extension, this should be the right answer. Adding the user to the directories' Access Control Lists is far better than changing the ownership, which can have plenty of unwanted knock-on effects.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same question when I tried to edit the nginx conf files on my VPS. There is an open issue at github: [Elevate rights on SSH remote](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/390), addressing similar problems.

As a temporary solution you can use WinScp - add sudo */path/to/sftp-server* to your connection settings and then you can save changes to most (if not any) file. [WinScp use sudo on login](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su#sudo).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am on macOS so I can't use WinScp has it is only for windows. It seems that the problem still persists based on this [opened issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48659). We will have to wait and see how it will be handled in the future I guess! Thanks again!

Comment: MS install a suite of utilities on the remote linux machine, one is the "code" command which will open the specified file in the Local VSC window.  So I thought I'd run that through sudo and got this error "Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal."

Answer (score 5):

Easiest solution for configuring files on a remote machine using a VSCode ssh (I use an Ubuntu EC2 instance with AWS) is to modify the file privileges while you work on the files using chmod.

By default, server config files (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default) are read-only (require sudo to write/save). There are open issues to allow VSCode SSH sudo access, however no good solution that I was able to find.

When you need to configure server files in dev, run this in your command-line SSH (non-VSCode) with sudo privileges:

`sudo chmod a+rwx /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

(or whatever your path to server config file is).

You can then ssh with VSCode and save the edited file freely.

If you don't like working in vim through the command line and want to use VSCode to edit server config files, this might be the quickest solution. Don't forget to switch file permissions back to read-only when you're done:

`sudo chmod -R 0444 /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: makes sense. Its like unlocking the door while you're busy, to make things easy . Then when you're done lock up again. Especially if its not a shared server and there is no password access, only SSH key access

Comment: This can be a major security problem. You shouldn't do this, and if you DO do this, for the love of god, disable it when you're done. (Though god help you if you do this on, say, a `public_html` folder, because the correct original permissions AREN'T 0444 on those folders.)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite answering your question, but a workaround nonetheless...

I have the same issue in a purely Dev environment (the remote Linux box is not in Production, and I have the root password). I worked around it by connecting as root whilst restricting where you can connect as root from.

- Follow the inctructions for setting up your authorized_keys file, but do the steps as root instead of your user:
  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_configuring-key-based-authentication
- Edit (vi) your root authorized_keys file which should have an entry that looks something like

`ssh-rsa ...Lots of text... dev@host`

- Change the entry so that it reads:

`from="9.8.7.6" ssh-rsa ...Lots of text... dev@host`
(where 9.8.7.6 is your VSCode dev machine)

Edit the connection entry under VSCode so that it reads something like:

`# Read more about SSH config files: https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config
Host linuxdev
    HostName linuxdev.resolvable.fqdn
    User root`

All of the above assumes that you know the root password and that sshd_config already has `PermitRootLogin=yes`.

If you want to further restrict the SSH root login from your VSCode Dev machine, then you could set `PermitRootLogin=no` globally in sshd_config and add a new restriction within sshd_config like this (at the end of the file):
`Match Host 9.8.7.6
    PermitRootLogin yes`

Then restart sshd (`systemctl restart sshd`) for the new SSHD permission to apply.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for Linux I just came across is to use `bindfs` (`sudo apt install bindfs`).

To enable editing `/etc/nginx` as `root` for the current user, working in `~/.bind-mounts/nginx`:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.bind-mounts/nginx
sudo bindfs --map=root/${USER}:@root/@$(id -gn) /etc/nginx ~/.bind-mounts/nginx
sudo umount ~/.bind-mounts/nginx # When you're done, or run bindfs with '-f' to keep it in the foreground
```

`bindfs` has many [options](https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html). `--map` may not be the best. It's been working in my testing so far.

Everything seems to work as you'd expect. Lets you "explore" as `root` and any modifications will be made as if you had `root`'s permissions. Just don't forget the security implications!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using [SSH FS VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs), and connecting to AWS EC2 Amazon Linux AMI, then below configuration should allow you editing files and saving with `sudo` permissions:

File: settings.json

```json
"sshfs.configs": [
{
  "name": "your-config-name",
  "host": "your-host-name.compute.amazonaws.com",
  "username": "ec2-user",
  "privateKeyPath": "/path/to/ssh-key-in-ED25519-format.pem",
  "port": 22,
  "debug": false,
  "sftpSudo": true,
  "sftpCommand": "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"
}
]
```

Another possible value for "sftpCommand" json key is: "/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server".

Answer (score -3):

I connect to the remote Ubuntu machine from the local VSCode using SSH and install VSCode inside the Ubuntu machine. I was able to create the files but can't write anything there.

I need to write a Prometheus config file and this is how I gave the write permission:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and write:

`PermitRootLogin yes`

After that login using

`ssh root@<Machine_IP>`

Comment: This opens additional security risks.

Answer (score -3):

### sudo

`sudo su -`

### Change file permissions

`sudo chmod -R 777 .`

Answer (score -4):

I have meet the same error, but I have watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwdRm18NaC8), thanks help me.

```
sudo chown -R username dictoryname
```

[image: vscode file]

Comment: There are already some "answers" like this. None of them answer the original question. What makes it worse, it is dangerous and _not_ recommended to change file/dir owner of services (or even root user) to an arbitrary user. It is not secure and calls for trouble.